# Ode solver in python

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve an ODE (dx^2/dt^2 = -4(x^2+y^2)^(3/2)) using scipy odeint, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def system(x,t,y):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    y1 = y

    dx1_dt = x2
    dx2_dt = -4*(x1**2+y1**2)**(3/2)
    dx_dt = [dx1_dt,dx2_dt]

    return dx_dt


x_0 = [2,3]
y_0 = [8,6]

t = np.linspace(0,1,30)
x_solved = odeint(system,x_0,t,args=(y_0[0]))
```

I am getting this error:

```
odepack.error: Extra arguments must be in a tuple
```

But I am passing the extra arguments as a tuple: `args=(y_0[0])`. What am i doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple with single element should be in the format
`(y_0[0],)`. Note the comma.

`(x)` evaluates to `x`
`(x,)` evaluates to a tuple with one element

`( )` are often used for syntactic and better readability reasons.
`is_true = (x and y) or (a or k)`

Since `( )` are already used for creating tuples, the way to differentiate a single element tuple and an expression is that `comma`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just for the future, what is the logic of that comma (I mean why would (x) evaluate to just one element)?

Comment: @BillKet, because parentheses are also used for grouping expressions.  E.g. `(x + 1)*2` should not be interpreted as "a tuple of length 1 containing `x + 1`, multiplied by 2".